Why take census of Levis two ways, from 1 month and between ages 30 & 50?
The tribes of Levi are counted twice: (a) from age one month with no upper age limit, and (b) from age 30 to 50.  Why is the first count needed? (This described in parshot Bamidbar and Naso.)

The first census allowed the redemption of the first-borns against the Leviim. Each of them were counted from age one month and up.
One month is the standard age in Jewish law for verifying that a baby is viable; that may explain this feature for both groups (Rashbam).

I have changed the question based on your input.

So I changed my answer too!
